# SSRS 2008 R2 Change First Day of the Week to Monday

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

This report aggregates data from the top by week into days using a drill down. Now, I'm just extracting the date parts from the date so I can group on the tables, and it works beautifully *however*, the first day of the week is set to 7, or sunday and I need it to start at 1, or monday. The obvious solution I've read is to `SET DATEFIRST 1` - incidentally, when I try to use `SET`, I get an error message saying that it is not supported

I've read you can change the global settings of the report to do this - but I have no clue where and would prefer to be able to do it locally in this query if possible. Also, I've tinkered around with `@@DATEFIRST` but all it does, of course, is report that the first day of the week is 7.

```
SELECT     DATENAME(week, CAST(Date AS date)) AS week, DATENAME(dw, CAST(Date AS date)) AS day, CONVERT(date, Date, 103) AS date, FROM_NUMBER, DURATION, 
                  TYPE_OF_CALL, ID, DATEPART(dw, CAST(Date - 1 AS date)) AS dayCode
FROM         CallCenterStatsCDR
WHERE     (Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY DATENAME(week, CAST(Date AS date)), CONVERT(date, Date, 103), DATENAME(dw, CAST(Date AS date)), FROM_NUMBER, DURATION, TYPE_OF_CALL, ID, 
                  DATEPART(dw, CAST(Date - 1 AS date))
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: What happens when you try the set datefirst independently?  Like this >>> 
SELECT @@DATEFIRST; SET DATEFIRST 1; SELECT @@DATEFIRST;

Comment: SET isn't allowed anywhere, the SQL won't parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datefirst function will impact all of the processes running on the server.  Could you DateAdd(dd,1,YourDate) all of your date fields in the query to get the same result?

Comment: excellent solution, thank you. I added this to my week column - `DATENAME(week, DATEADD(dd, - 1, CAST(Date AS date)))`